# How to get a subselection of a D3.js selection

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to get a subselection of a given D3.js selection.

This part of the code creates the paths:

```
pieces.paths = pieces.groups
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return d.data.color; });
```

Then, I set de "d" attribute:

```
pieces.paths
    .attr("d", arc);
```

Working perfect. But pieces.paths has 3 elements, and I want to set the class of the first two elements to "highest". How may I do that?

Comment: `.attr("class",function(d){isFirstTwo(d) ? return 'highest' : return ''})` Just write some conditional or function that will return true for the first two elements but not the rest.

Comment: Thats works. But isn't this solution expensive? I would like to iterate just the first two elements. If there is a thousand elements in the group, it will iterate over all them. Is there another way? @elsherbini

Comment: if you do it when you are appending the paths in the first place, you are iterating over the data anyway, so it's just the cost of 1000 if statements, not a whole other loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[selection.filter()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) is one option:

```
pieces.paths
    .filter(function(d, i) {return i<2;})
    .attr("class", "highest");
```

Comment: [Copied comment] Thats works. But isn't this solution expensive? I would like to iterate just the first two elements. If there is a thousand elements in the group, it will iterate over all them. Is there another way?

Comment: You could access the DOM elements directly: `pieces.paths[0][0].setAttribute('class', 'highest');`